# loop issue with automatic gifts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make a program for school that calculates given gifts.

The program should look as work as follows:

Program asks how many buyers, and every every second buyer will get a free gift as - first buyer will get one gift, second will get nothing, third will get three gifts and so on

For example, if user enters 8 buyers, then the sum would be 16 because 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16

The below version worked but....

```
buyers = int(input("Input how many buyers: "))
i = 1
while i < buyers:
    i = i * 4
print("Free gifts " + str(i))
```

If user entered 2 then the program should give 1 but this one gave 2.
If user entered 3, 7 or 8 then the answer was correct.
But if user entered for example 100 then I expected a answer 2500 but program gave me 256.

I would appriciate if someone would help me out with this one.

Comment: If you enter `2` for the input into `buyers`, then `i=1`, `1 < 2` is `True`, and `i = i * 4` (so the end result is 4).

Comment: Ugh, I would do the same but as school just requests using   while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a constraint where you are required to use a while loop, I assume you're taking an intro course to python and aren't exposed to list comprehensions yet. While this is far from a pythonic approach, this is probably within the constructs of where you are in your course.

The key (unless you can do it in a one liner) is that you will need to have a separate variable to track the gifts independently of the buyers. It's also helpful to identify the pattern of how free gifts are distributed, which is simply the sum of all odd numbers below the number of buyers.

```
buyers = int(input("Input how many buyers: "))

gifts = 0

i = 0
while i < buyers:

    if i % 2 == 1:
        gifts += i

    i += 1

print("Free gifts " + str(gifts))
```

If you were to put it in a function, it would be easy to quickly test.

```
def how_many_gifts(buyers):

    gifts = 0

    i = 0
    while i < buyers:

        if i % 2 == 1:
            gifts += i

        i += 1

    return gifts
```

Test a range of inputs.

```
outstr = "{} buyers = {} free gifts"

for i in range(11):
    print(outstr.format(i, how_many_gifts(i)))

print(outstr.format(100, how_many_gifts(100)))
```

and get the following output

```
0 buyers = 0 free gifts
1 buyers = 0 free gifts
2 buyers = 1 free gifts
3 buyers = 1 free gifts
4 buyers = 4 free gifts
5 buyers = 4 free gifts
6 buyers = 9 free gifts
7 buyers = 9 free gifts
8 buyers = 16 free gifts
9 buyers = 16 free gifts
10 buyers = 25 free gifts
100 buyers = 2500 free gifts
```

The one liner approach would be

```
gifts = sum(range(1, buyers+1, 2))
```

This kind of brevity is why python can be a real pleasure to work in.

Comment: I like the one-liner, well done! But I have to admit with @Prune 's respond, you have to add 1 to the buyers variable, else it won't return a gift on "1" buyer

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
buyers = int(input("Input how many buyers: "))
gifts = sum([item for item in list(range(buyers+1))[1::2]])

print("Free gifts " + str(gifts))
```

it's the sum of all numbers up to n+1 with a stride of 2

Edit - with while:

```
buyers = int(input('Input how many buyers'))
to_sum = [item for item in list(range(buyers+1))[1::2]]
gifts=0
while len(to_sum) != 0:
    gifts+=to_sum[0]
    to_sum.pop(0)

print('Free gifts: ' + str(gifts))
```

Comment: This would do the trick, but as automatic check also requires `while` in the program

Comment: ammended answer to satisfy constraints :P

Answer (score 0):

Your posted program finds the largest power of 4 that's <= the quantity of buyers; I'm not sure how that is supposed to relate to the problem given.

Your assignment, in mere arithmetic terms, is to add up all the odd numbers <= the quantity of buyers:

```
# Get the input as you're already doing

i = 1
gifts = 0

while i <= buyers:
    gifts += i
    i += 2

# Print the output as you're already doing
```

As a one-liner:

```
gifts = sum(range(1, buyers+1, 2))
```